# Fast or automatic way to organize iphone/ipod apps

Tags: itunes, iphone, ipod

Is there a tool or application that can help me quickly organize my iphone applications?  The standard way of dragging and dropping 1 application at a time in folder is too frustrating for me.  I gave up after 1 hour of trying... I found it to be such a waste of time ...

I am looking for an application to automatically organize my apps in the standard folder categories at least (Productivity, Navigation, Photography, etc).  I was not able to find one in the iTunes store.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Connect your phone to iTunes, go to your phone in the sidebar, and select the Apps tab. There you should find some slightly less tedious app management where you can rearrange icons and/or screens. Perform a sync when you're finished reorganizing.

There's also a Jailbreak app called MultiIconMover, but the Jailbreak apps for messing with icons is a whole other kettle of fish...

Comment: Hehe, that's the slowest way one can do it. It drove me absolutely insane!

Comment: There's also a Jailbreak app called SpringSorter which will automatically sort by usage if you really hate organizing by hand, but of course Jailbreaking isn't for everyone. But as for non-Jailbreak, iTunes is the only organization available to you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do it one icon at a time: just hold `SHIFT` to multi-select icons on a single page!

(You can multi-select folders along with the icons, too).

Then you can drag them all at once to a new page, or inside an existing folder (or out of a folder).

Much faster than one at a time!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you been doing the organisation on the device, or in iTunes? I find iTunes a lot easier for this.

Comment: It's not easy at all.  It's insanely slow when you have many applications.

Answer (score 0):

Take look at this video. You create category and then go select apps you want in that category from list as oppose to dragging them. I find it a lot more faster and easier to do:
[InstallerApps](http://www.wonderhowto.com/how-to-organize-icons-your-iphone-209582/)

Comment: Is that jailbroken only?

Comment: I had previously tried this.  It's not working very well for me ... I prefer to either do it automatically (by the standard iTunes Apps categories) or to select an application to place it in a category rather than the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

There is a jailbreak tweak called mutliIconMover which will let you move multiple icons at once. I find it indispensable for quickly re-arranging my icons.